# An android app to track the geolocation of my friends’ iOS phones?

Tags: android, ios, iphone-app, geo-location

I have an Android phone and my friends and family have iPhones.

If we were all on iPhones I could use the [*Find my friends*](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201493) app to find out where they are.

Is there an app I can use that will give me the same functionality from my Android phone?

Comment: Is it OK to require all of your friends to install a particular app? Or should it work without requiring them to do anything special (besides giving permissions)?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul. It’s fine if it requires them to install a particular app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside of Google Maps on the phone

[image]

[image]

Select your email from the list.
[image]

Click getting started

Elsewhere in settings it is possible to turn on a higher accuracy of settings.